# How add menu to my node programmatically?

Tags: 8, nodes, navigation

This is how i create my node :

```
    $value= array(
                'type' => 'page',              
                'title'=>"First node",
                'body' => array(
                    'value' => "test",
                    'format' => 'full_html',
                ),
);

$nodeEntity=\Drupal::entityTypeManager()
            ->getStorage('node')
            ->create($value);

        $nodeEntity->save();
```

This work fine.

But i try to give a menu parent to this node.

i try that :

```
$value= array(
            'type' => 'page',              
            'title'=>"First node",
            'body' => array(
                'value' => "test",
                'format' => 'full_html',
            ),
            'menu'=>array(
             'title'=>"First node",
             'menu_parent'=>6,
             'description' => '',
             'enabled'=>1

        ),
```

);

i set the field menu because it's the name of the field in the node edit form.
But for the nodeEntity, this field doesn't exist.

How can i give a parent menu id to my node ?

**UPDATE**

if i set menu_link instead of menu, i got no error i still can't see the menu on the node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After look into the database and some test, this is how i add a menu to my node on the creation or on node update :

For this example, i load a node :

```
  $nodeEntity=\Drupal::entityTypeManager()
            ->getStorage('node')
            ->load(312);
```

> After you create the link :

```
$menu_link = MenuLinkContent::create([
    'title' => 'name of your menu',
    'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/node/' . $nodeEntity->id()],
    'menu_name' => 'main',
    'expanded' => TRUE,
]);

$menu_link->save();
```

If you want add a parent to your menu just add this in $menu_link :

> $menu parent is the uuid of the parent menu

```
'parent' => 'menu_link_content:' . $menuParent,
```

> Then you need to update menu_link_content_data

```
  $this->database->update('menu_link_content_data')
            ->fields([
                'link__uri' => 'entity:node/'.$nodeEntity->id(),
            ])
            ->condition('id', $menu_link->id())
            ->execute();
```

The link between the menu and the node is the link__uri, you need to tell him to reference the entity node.

After that, you ll see your menu link on your node.

I haven't find better solution with Drupal API for now.